# Export JSON Data to Highchart (Pie)

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, json, highcharts

I'm trying to render a highchart from an MYSQL Query. The JSON looks correct, the page loads without any error, but it won't render the highchart.

My Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - jsFiddle demo</title>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fiddle.jshell.net/css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fiddle.jshell.net/css/result-light.css">
  <style type='text/css'>        
  </style>
<script type='text/javascript'>

$(function () {
    var chart;
    var myJson =  
[{"Buch":"0528713FHVR ","Anzahl":3},{"Buch":"0657222FHVR","Anzahl":2},{"Buch":"A10055035","Anzahl":2},{"Buch":"0657223FHVR","Anzahl":1},{"Buch":"062729XFHVR","Anzahl":1}] 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var options = {
        chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: null,
                plotShadow: false
            },
            title: {
                text: 'My PIE chart'
            },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage}%</b>',
                percentageDecimals: 1
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        color: '#000000',
                        connectorColor: '#000000',
                        formatter: function() {
                            return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.percentage +' %';
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            series: []
    };
        var seriesNew = {
                type: 'pie',
                name: 'Some series name',
                data: []
            };
        myJson = $.parseJSON(myJson);
        jQuery.each(myJson, function (itemNo, item) {
            seriesNew.data.push({
                x: item.Buch,
                y: item.Anzahl
            })
        });
        options.series.push(seriesNew);       
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I didn't include the SQL Query, since I feel like the JSON ist well formatted (i used JSON_Encode).

But i have no idea why it won't render.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have a JSON, you don't need to parse it using jQuery, so remove that line: `myJson = $.parseJSON(myJson);` and should work. See: http://jsfiddle.net/H4LS9/

Edit:

To get first value as slice name use point as an array: http://jsfiddle.net/H4LS9/1/

```
        seriesNew.data.push([
           item.Buch,
           item.Anzahl
        ])
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks a lot. No idea why i haven't seen that. Now i have to try an get the captions like 0657222FHVR instead of slice.